# To get which function/line threw exception in javascript

Tags: javascript, exception

I am trying to create a Exception class to get and send errors from client to server. I want to catch exception in javascript function and push the details to the web service to write to database.

But i couldn't get how to get which function/line throwed this exception. Is there any way to solve this?

[image: This is just what i have in exception object]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library: http://eriwen.com/javascript/stacktrace-update/